# Deny Drop DB Objects in Sql Server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-grant

I need help to set GRANT CREATE, ALTER BUT DENY DROP DB Objects to db users using sql server 2008.

I've tried this but it returns error:

```
use DBName
GO
DENY DROP TO dbUser
Error: Incorrect syntax near 'DROP'.
```

Any help would be much appreciated.
Many thanks..

rfs

Comment: I thought it was: DENY DROP ON table TO dbUser

Answer (score 1):

There is no `DROP` permission but instead you need to use `DELETE`

in your case code will be as follows

```
USE DBName
GO
DENY DELETE to dbuser
```

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188338.aspx